# Swipe Tabs list are not changing in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

Actually, i having a list which containing 33 names.
I am displaying 10 records in each swipe tabs and also added radio button dynamically for 33 records its creating 4 radio buttons. So, my issue is my second and third swipe tabs only displaying the first tab 10 records while my fourth tabs are displaying correctly the last three records while I am getting the exact record for each tab through the web service call.

```
for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++){

                if(radioList.get(i).getName().equals(radioButtonName)){
                    val=newSelected;
                    if(newSelected==0){
                        lowerBound=Constants.PAGELOWERBOUND;
                        upperBound=Constants.PAGEUPPERBOUND;
                        nameListBean=getSwipeTabsValues(lowerBound,upperBound); 
                        displayContainer.removeAll();
                        getDisplay(displayContainer);
                        displayContainer.revalidate();
                    }else{
                        Log.p("Comming here");
                        int val=newSelected;
                        int multipleVal=val*Constants.PAGEUPPERBOUND+1;
                        lowerBound=multipleVal;
                        upperBound=multipleVal+9;
                        nameListBean=getSwipeTabsValues(lowerBound,upperBound); 
                        displayContainer.removeAll();
                        getDisplay(displayContainer);
                        displayContainer.revalidate();
                    }
                    radioList.get(i).setSelected(true);
                }else{
                    radioList.get(i).setSelected(false);
                }

public void getDisplay(Container displayNamesContainer){
    //displayContainer1.removeAll();
     if(nameListBean!=null){
       displayNamesContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
       for(NamesBeans names:nameListBean.getNamesList()){
           Label name=new Label(names.getNames());
           Log.p("names======="+names.getNames());
           displayNamesContainer.add(name);
       }
       //displayContainer1.revalidate();
     }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is `getSwipeTabsValues(lowerBound,upperBound); ` returning the correct values for each tab selection?  Is `lowerBound` and `upperBound` what you expect for each run?

Comment: Yes its returning the correct value (means returning the 10 records ) for the selected tab but those 10 records are not displaying in the middle two tabs(suppose I have 4 tabs 1st tabs is showing particular 10 records and the last tab is showing particular  10 records but I am not able to display the coming 10 records in 2 and 3 tabs).

Comment: lowerBound and uperBound are 1 and 10

Comment: If they are always 1 and 10, then there's your problem.  Your intention looks like that they will be 1 and 10 for the first tab.  11 and 20, for the 2nd, etc..